# Setting task-id from trigger_dag_run_operator

Tags: airflow

Need help in below Airflow query:

Not able to set task-id, which is started using trigger_dag_run_operator:

Below are my trigger dag run operator and target python operator:
TriggerDag operator:

```
    ...
    trigger_target = TriggerDagRunOperator(
        task_id='trigger_target',
        trigger_dag_id='TargetDag',
        conf={"message": "Test Message", "executed_file_name":"DAG_NAME_001"},
    )
    ...
```

Target dag operator:

```
    trigger_pipeline = PythonOperator(
        task_id='called_for_file'+{{dag_run['conf']['executed_file_name']}},
        python_callable=call_trigger_pipeline,
    )
```

In the above code "{{dag_run['conf']['executed_file_name']}}" is not getting replaced with values set in trigger dag run operator.

Thanks,
Jack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with that code is that `task_id` is not a templated field so the Jinja won't get rendered, that explains why you get the output including the curly braces, that's the expected behaviour.

Without knowing further context, I think you should consider a different design where tasks don't get generated dynamically but `DAG`s do. Following the pattern from [Airflow FAQs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/faq.html?highlight=template_fields#how-to-create-dags-dynamically) you could create DAGs and further tasks dynamically, consider this example:

```py
def create_dags(city_name, payload: list, default_args):
    """
    Returns a DAG object
    """

    def _print_load_number(city_name, load_number):
        print(f"{load_number} from: {city_name} ")

    dag = DAG(
        f"location_sync_{city_name}",
        schedule_interval="@daily",
        catchup=False,
        tags=["example", "dynamic_dag"],
        default_args=default_args,
    )

    with dag:
        end = DummyOperator(task_id="end")
        for load_no in payload:
            print_load = PythonOperator(
                task_id=f"{dag_id}_proccesing_load_{load_no}",
                python_callable=_print_load_number,
                op_kwargs={"city_name": city, "load_number": load_no},
            )
            print_load >> end

    # DAG level tasks dependencies
    return dag

cities = [
    {"name": "London", "payload": [1, 2, 3]},
    {"name": "Paris", "payload": [4, 5, 6]},
    {"name": "Buenos_Aires", "payload": [4, 5, 6]},
]

default_args = {"owner": "Airflow", "start_date": days_ago(1)}

for city in cities:
    dag_id = city["name"]

    globals()[dag_id] = create_dags(city["name"], city["payload"], default_args)
```

Note that within `create_dag` function, Tasks are dynamically created and each `task_id` is named based on the provided values: `task_id=f"{dag_id}_proccesing_load_{load_no}"`

Once you get **n** DAGs created, then you can handle triggering them however you need, including using `TriggerDagRunOperator` from another DAG, which will allow to define (dynamically) the `dag_id` to be triggered. You could even  loop through the same `iterable` used while creating the DAGs.

Also, since `trigger_dag_id` is a templated field,  if you need to define the DAG to be triggered from the UI or CLI you could use macros on `params` like this:

```py
trigger_service_discovery = TriggerDagRunOperator(
    task_id='trigger_loc_sync',
    trigger_dag_id='location_sync_{}'.format('{{ params.dag_id_from_UI }}'),
    wait_for_completion=True,
)
```

Graph view of one of the DAGs from the above example:

[image: graph_view]

Check the Astronomer's guide for further reading about [dynamic DAGs generation](https://www.astronomer.io/guides/dynamically-generating-dags).

Comment: Thanks Nicoe, this is one of the possibility will can check, but this solution will always create a new DAG right, if i want to add new tasks in existing dag with different task names will it allow in this way or i need to check for a different approach.

Comment: This approach only change the way DAGs are authored, instead of having code in `.py` modules for each DAG, you get to have one `.py` from where multiples DAGs are interpreted. Everything else is the same. Just keep in mind that if you add more tasks to the function `create_dags`, the three DAGs from the example will be changed.